# Solving a single, long linear equation in R - many unknown variables

Tags: r, equation-solving

I have a single twelve-term equation for different classes of disease prevalence (`nx`) that looks like this:

```
y = f*b0*n0 + f*b1*n1 + f*b2*n2 + ... + f*b12*n12
```

I also have an equality constraint, such that

```
n0 + n1 + n2 + ... + n12 = 1  ## prevalence must add up to one
```

The unknowns are nx (where x=[1,12] ).
I would prefer to solve this analytically, but can also make do with a numerical solution.
I would be grateful for any pointers on R packages or approaches (or is this unsolvable?). The project is in support of the current humanitarian response in Iraq - so hopefully a worthwhile cause.

Comment: Normally it has an infinite number of solutions. So the question is, which solution you are interested in? Till now it is an algebraic problem - not a programming problem.

Comment: Thanks both. All parameters are known save for n1..n12, namely the prevalences of (fractions of the population with) different disease risk factor profiles. y is the overall mean incidence (new disease cases) rate, f is the base incidence rate among the lowest risk profile, and the b's are multipliers for f that apply to each different risk profile (b0 is actually 1). I would like a solution that satisfies the constraint, and where each nx >0 and <1. Sorry if that doesn't help much!

Comment: Just to clarify: how many observations (values of `y` corresponding to a vector of `b` values) do you have?  If only a single one (or any value <12) then your problem is underdetermined (with the constraint, you need 11 separate y values). If exactly 11 then this can be solved by linear algebra.  If >11 this is an optimization problem (finding the best possible fit)

Comment: Thanks Ben. You're right, it's underdetermined (I have only a single y data point), just wasn't thinking straight. I think I need to go back to the drawing board and try something different. Thanks again.